# Bootstrap validator: force enter only numeric value

Tags: jquery, numeric, keyup

I am using Bootstrap validator.
https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator

But users are still entering char values.

while keyup char contents, i want abort write(or disable).

Which jquery plugin I can use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Comment: more thanks. finished.